# Access ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

```
  <div ng-controller="NotesController as noteCtrl">

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" style="float: left;width: 90%;" ng-model="newNoteText" >
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='noteCtrl.addNewNote()' type="button" style="margin-left: 0.5%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;ADD</button>

</div>
```

============================================

```
    var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("NotesController",function(){
  this.allNotes=notes;
  this.note={};
  this.addNewNote=function(){
    alert(newNoteText);
  };

});
```

Please let me know how to access the input text box value in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't even injecting the $scope variable. You want something like this:

```
app.controller('NotesController', function($scope) {
    $scope.allNotes=notes;
    $scope.note={};
    $scope.addNewNote = function(){
        alert($scope.newNoteText);
    };
});
```

No need to use `this` in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the scope variable:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("NotesController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.allNotes = $scope.notes;
    $scope.note = {};
    $scope.addNewNote = function () {
        console.log($scope.newNoteText);
    };
});
```

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto1/jmd646vy/).

Answer (score 0):

No need to inject $scope since you're using controllerAs.  Just replace this:

```
 ng-model="newNoteText"
```

with this:

```
ng-model="noteCtrl.newNoteText"
```

and in your controller replace this:

```
alert(newNoteText);
```

with this:

```
alert(this.newNoteText);
```